# Possible change Mako's inline begin/end syntax?

Tags: python, template-engine, jinja2, mako

I've been using Jinja2 to create and render templates of Bash scripts (among other things) and  I've been missing the power of having full python available as in Mako.

The thing that keeps me from using Mako at the moment seems rather trivial which is that Mako's inline begin/end `${`/`}` syntax clashes with Bash's own syntax (and Jinja2's does not)

So what I want to know is: Is there any way to change Mako's begin/end `${`/`}` syntax to be something else, where that something else is something that doesn't clash with Bash.

(Otherwise, am I missing something obvious?)

Answer (score 1):

run your templates through a [preprocessor](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#mako.template.Template.params.preprocessor):

```
from mako.template import Template
import re

def bash_preprocessor(source):
    source = re.sub(r"\${(.+?)}", r"${'${'}\1${'}'}", source)
    source = re.sub(r"\^\[(.+?)\]", r"${\1}", source)
    return source

t = Template("""

BAR='hi'
BAT='^[hoho]'
PATH='/path/to/crap'

EXECUTABLE=${PATH}/${BAR}/${BAT}

""", preprocessor=bash_preprocessor)


print t.render(hoho="boo")
```